# Error running Java on Sublime Text [OSX]

Tags: java, macos, sublimetext3

So I've tried to start compiling and running java on sublime, and it works fine if the package is not defined.

this compile and run:

```
public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("this is a test.");  
    }
}
```

But if I add a package:

```
package test;

public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("this is a test.");  
    }   
}
```

I got this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Tester
[Finished in 6.8s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['javac "Tester.java" && java "Tester"']]
[dir: /Users/ph/Documents/JAVA/test]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Any idea why is this happening or how to fix it?

Comment: I think because you added a package you would have to create a folder called test then put Tester.java in it and then run it outside of the test folder.     java test.Tester to run it

Comment: yeah, that's how is structured, it was always inside a folder called 'test' that's why i added the package but only compile without it, en if i complie it and run it from terminal it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. [cmd: ['javac "Tester.java" && java "Tester"']]
2. [dir: /Users/ph/Documents/JAVA/test]

Sublime Text is trying to compile your program in a directory called "test" (see #2), which is the package name. It is looking for a file named "Tester.java" within that directory (see #1), but it doesn't exist because "Tester.java" is inside the current directory ("JAVA").

When compiling Java files in packages, the files need to be in a directory structure that reflects the package hierarchy. So you need to move your file to the directory that corresponds to the package it is contained in. For example, class "A" in package example.utils.letters would have to exist at the path ../example/utils/letters/A.java

Create folder "JAVA/test" and move Tester.java into there, then run it.

Comment: thanks for answering, but i know how to organize files, and that's where the file is, that's why i'm asking, because i don't know why sublime can't find the main class if it is in the same directory, in fact when i compile and run from terminal it works corectly.